# Smooth Div Scroll | Left / Right Hotspots Misfiring after browser resized

Tags: html, browser, resize, smooth-scrolling

The smoothDivScroll works perfectly, until the user resizes the browser window.

After the browser window has been resized by the user, the hotspots on both the left and right side start to misbehave.

For instance, sometimes the left hotspot will stop working all together, other times the speed variation will be non existant and it will only scroll at a super fast speed or super slow speed. The same can be said for the right hot spot.

Everything else seems to work fine.

Container element for the scrollable content is at a fixed ratio.

Height: 404px
Width: 780px

Check it out:

http://www.brendenmersey.com/dev/andreatiller/portfolio/index.html

What have I done wrong?

*first post on 'overflow, so please bear with me :D*

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your demo and everything seems to be correct. I think this is a bug in Smooth Div Scroll that I will have to take a look at.

Thanks for posting it here on Stackoverflow! I have added it as [a new issue on the GitHub page](https://github.com/tkahn/Smooth-Div-Scroll/issues/45).